# TypeScript - get type of constructor of a pure class type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to use `typeof` operator to get the constructor type from class, but it doesn't seem to work when you want to use it on a dictionary of classes. E.g. `typeof Modules[T]` - instead of getting the type of `Modules[T]`, the compiler thinks of (typeof Modules)[T]

```
class A { }

class B { }

abstract class Modules {
    public a!: A;
    public b!: B;
}

// Error: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'typeof Modules'
function addModule<T extends keyof Modules>(key: T, ModuleCtor: typeof Modules[T]) {
    let module = new ModuleCtor();
}

addModule('a', A);

// Works but the constructor arguments type is lost
function addModule2<T extends keyof Modules>(
    key: T,
    ModuleCtor: new (...args:any[]) => Modules[T]
) {
    let module = new ModuleCtor();
}

addModule2('a', A);
```

[Playground url](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQrSRgIUS9YARhAC4BOYwJ0mU0AsgPYAmAriAKYwKrR-QAHVoRABLYNDABCAFxwA3L35CR46IVnRsitKgD0e6AFEyZRmTkAVAJ4CO0AOSWHNMADs3jaoXusIHZmgSRmhRN2YOAA8g23sHEljGADMGFnYuB1Qk1jcqUUY3SWZmJjZOAB5LaCiSDnCYAGsOa2TUsq4APgAKJusrABo29IBhYIsYu1bS9IgAbUsAXQBKRCU+TmoAWzTOaABeaDcOAHchzlHzLqWdAmLpzi6HMAdB2Gv0A2gAdXMGmEJWNQSAALezAAqkMisKjmSRkADmrE2dRIMASdlCMBAjFIWRyeQKRRKOw4ACZKtVIrV6tBelMSRBumtac0Bsz7hwLuMjqcugA6AVgBEQGTuayzZb7DpnLjzBaoFY8fjQDbQbbtfaHE4yrlXG6oMB3Emkx7PV7XIA)

## Update

As Aleksey pointed out, `typeof` operator works only on values. Classes are actual values, but what I have here is pure types. I'm essentially looking for something that works like `typeof Class (value)` that would get the exact type of constructor (including its arguments) of a pure class type.

Comment: You can't use `typeof` with type, it should be used with value. That's why first attempt doesn't work

Comment: `typeof` can be used to get the type of class constructor. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQqBmBXAdsALgJYD2O0hOhRYIhAXgKYDC4UAFE-sQE4Bc0+AJ4AHBsQxwAlIlTQ50YKQj5yOZWDwNoAXmg4GAd2icebSQG5UyIA

Comment: Of course, if you use it with class/function which is value. `Modules[T]` is a type

Comment: Aha. Now I understand, thank you! I also understand now that the `new (...args:any[]) => Modules[T]` solution I had earlier is good enough, as it would be hard for the class that returns the same thing to have different constructor arguments. Although I still wonder if is there a "typeof" equivalent for a class-type that would get the exact type of the constructor, including the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that you have to remember Typescript types are based on the Shape of an interface, there not Hard Types.

So in your example ->
class A { } and class B { } are the same Type..

So the first thing we need to do is in your example is make A & B different somehow, so that Typescript can know the difference.

Otherwise you could do -> `addModule('a', B);` and I'm assuming you want to trap that.

eg.

```
class A { A?:string }
class B { B?:string }
```

In the above, class A & B types are now different, in a real application it's likely that your methods etc are different, so doing a dummy `A?:string` wouldn't normally be required.

The next problem is we need to define the shape of our constructor, if your constructor is empty, a simple example would be ->

`type Construct<T> = new () => T;`

After doing this our final result is ->

```
class A {
    A?: string
}

class B {
    B?: string
}

class Modules {
    a!: A;
    b!: B;
}

type Construct<T> = new () => T;

function addModule<T extends keyof Modules, C extends Construct<Modules[T]>>(key: T, ModuleCtor: C) {
  const x = new ModuleCtor()
}

var a = addModule('a', A)

//Argument of type 'typeof B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct<A>'.
var a = addModule('a', B)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ04H4Bc0IBcBOAlgHYDmSAvkkqJDAEKIrR2bb7FmXXhTQCyAewAmAVxABTGMlSowAQiywA3E1QAjBcxVccATwAO46AGEBRXHhHAcAHgAqAPmgBeaEXEB3aAAoAlC6c7FSQAMxEiawIzaDAhIUFRCXtocQAPHHEiIRgAa3FdARD%20YTFJABoTFPTM7JMzCytbBNKIAG07AF0HB2883Sw7CuaJYxwBPCxjf2loYHqcaFSXN09ixPFR8b8KKgA3MDwY5dj4kolvAHIwC4rYXyoAegfYPBIRAFtMhcLoPUNoC5-cQ-OgXaAEGBEAQLWgEEhEMBqCS-ATQfQHMCfDKHH5AgGmcz4Ro2WAOC4AOiQ%200OYGOcWG4ku1wqdF8QA)

Comment: `new () => T` - This works only if we assume the constructor accepts no arguments. I had this in my question: `ModuleCtor: new (...args:any[]) => Modules[T]` - which is a bit more universal as it works with or without arguments. I am essentially looking for something that could get the exact type of the class, down to exact constructor arguments. `typeof` can do just that if the class is an actual value, I'm looking for the same solution for pure class types.